# How to switch Excel sheet by clicking on specific cell? VSTO C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, event-handling, vsto

My intention is to make a clickable "table of contents" on the first worksheet.
So, a worksheet change could be arranged by

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1).select();
```

**But how can I act on a click at a cell in a specific range?Without putting too much strain on the process.**

Finally I want to check the text of a cell whether it contains a sheet name. If yes jump to that sheet. Like:

```
string cellText = activeCell.Value2;

foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets)
        {
            if (sheet.Name.Equals(cellText)
            {
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[sheetName].select();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe someone knows an approach for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution but for the moment it works for me.

Because it's an VSTO Excel AddIn, I have a ribbon. So, at ribbon_load() register an event.

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.SheetSelectionChange += new Excel.AppEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler(myApplication_SheetSelectionChange);
}
```

At the event I check which cell fired the event and what content is inside the cell.

```
    private void myApplication_SheetSelectionChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
    {   
        if (((Excel.Worksheet)GetInstance().ActiveSheet).Name.Equals(Statics.NAME_OVERVIEW))   //  if sheet overview
        {
            if (Target.Row > 6 && Target.Column == 9)
            {                    
                try
                {
                    string tmp = Target.Value2;
                    tmp = tmp.Replace("'", "");

                    if (tmp.StartsWith("="))
                    {
                        foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in GetInstance().Worksheets)
                        {
                            if (sheet.Name.Equals(tmp))
                            {
                                sheet.Select();       //  jump to sheet
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }
        }
        else            //  all other sheets - jump back to overview
        {
            if (Target.Row == 42 && Target.Column == 1)
            {
                ((Excel.Worksheet)GetInstance().Sheets[Statics.NAME_OVERVIEW]).Select();
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe that helps someone.